# Some condition for unitary operator to be identity.

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

- $U$ and $T$ are positive self adjoint operators.
- $K$ is unitary/orthogonal.
- $U = T \circ K$

Proof that $K=I$.
I tried to show that $\forall x <x-Kx,x-Kx>=0$, but got stuck. The only equation I managed to show is $<Kx,Ty>=<Tx,Ky> \forall x,y$. Can you give me some hints?

Comment: What if $U$ and $T$ are zero?

Comment: @Demophilus Are you trying to say that in this case $K$ can be any unitary/orthogonal operator? Let's assume they aren't zero.

Comment: Then what if U and T are projections?

Comment: @Demophilus if $U$=$U^2$ and $T=T^2$? What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $U=T= \left( \begin{matrix} 1 &0\\ 0&0 \end{matrix} \right)$ and $K= \left( \begin{matrix} 1 &0\\ 0&-1 \end{matrix} \right)$ then $U=TK$ but $K \neq I$.

Comment: Well, looks like my statement was a lie. Thank you.